# Finding the median of multiple columns from a csv file

Tags: python

I need to create a function that will take each columns from a csv dataset and return its median value. For example:

```
def calc_median(column)
```

I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(data)
median = df.median()
return median

calc_median('column name')
```

Then it gave me the median of all the columns instead of the one column I called for.

I need to make this function so that when I input a specific column, it will return the column's median, not all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

to select one column in dataframe just do

```
iris_data['nameofcolun'].median()
```

Comment: This adds the median of only one column into my function and I'm not able to draw medians for the other columns.

Comment: @Yeet try 
`def medianfinder(column_name):
            retrurn iris_data[str(column_name)].median()
`

Answer (score 0):

```
def iris_median(col):
    print(iris_data[col].median())
```